# Flutter - Checkbox animation doesn't show

Tags: flutter, dart

The value is effectively changing when clicking but the animation doesn't show :

[image]

Here's my code :

```
 var editGender = Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CheckboxListTile(
            value: _male,
            onChanged: _maleChanged,
            title: Text("Male"),
            activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
          CheckboxListTile(
            value: _female,
            onChanged: _femaleChanged,
            title: Text("Female"),
            activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          )  
        ],
      ),
    );
```

When tapping the edit button :

```
    FlatButton(
      onPressed: (){
          buildShowRoundedModalBottomSheet(context, title, editGender, option);
      },
      child: Text('Edit'),
```

it shows the bottom sheet :

```
Future buildShowRoundedModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context, String title, Widget content,[String date]) {
    return showRoundedModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        radius: 20.0,
        builder: (context){
          
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'SamsungSans',
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
                content,
                ...
```

I am passing the same context to the widget :/

Comment: Your bottom sheet(or whatever it is) doesn't seem like it is rebuilding.

Comment: Ow yes, that's true ! So I have to but the bottom sheet within a `Builder` widget ?

Comment: `StatefulBuilder` might be more helpful.

Comment: May be your state is handled by the class that calls to show the BottomSheet. The state is on different context the dosen't invoke rebuild.

Comment: It's weird. I am passing the same context to the bottom sheet.

Comment: @user54517 Did you make use of https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html?

Comment: Yes, and it's the same

Comment: May I know what does `showRoundedModalBottomSheet` return? Maybe adding the code of that function to your question will help.

Comment: It is this plugin : https://github.com/gildaswise/rounded_modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` would change the value but it wouldn't rebuild your bottom sheet as it is being called on a `onPressed` of a `FlatButton`. You are certainly not invoking that `onPressed` again but you wouldn't want to do it either.

As I mentioned in the comments a `StatefulBuilder` would do the job.

A working example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rounded_modal/rounded_modal.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  bool value = false;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    showRoundedModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
            return Container(
              height: 200.0,
              child: Checkbox(value: value, onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  value = val;
                });
              }),
            );
          });
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: bottomsheet]

Comment: I tried to wrap both `content` or directly the `editGender` with StatefulBuilder builder but nothing. I'm happy to see that it is supposed to work, but I really don't understand where that could come from. Is it because I work on different files ? I don't think so 'cause I'm transmitting the correct context

Comment: I didn't get what your are saying. You must wrap `Padding(....` with  `StatefulBuilder `.

Comment: Which padding ?

Comment: No not that. I am talking about the padding in your `showRoundedModalBottomSheet`.

Comment: Oh yeah I tried it too, but still the same result :/

Comment: Correct. so `setState` in the `StatefulBuilder` is to be used. I am not sure what your `CheckboxListTile` is doing, but it must make use of the `setState` of the `StatefulBuilder` to work.

Comment: Ow, okay I understand. The file containing the `buildShowRoundedModalBottomSheet` function is a 'util' file, supposed to be used by any file that would need it. Is doesn't contain all the variables related to the profile (which are in a ProfilePage.dart file).  Is there another way to do things ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196698/discussion-between-10101010-and-user54517).

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @10101010, you'll have to use a Stateful widget. And In _femaleChanged and _maleChanged, you'll have to use setState(). Example :

```
void _femaleChanged(bool value) =>  setState(() => _female = value);
```

Comment: That's already the case. I am using a statefulwidget to st the state. Otherwise you would not see the value changing. What I don't understand is why the animation doesn't show.